# Creating KnowledgeArticleViewStat Test data for Apex Testing

Tags: apex

Is there anyway to create KnowledgeArticleViewStat test data for particular article types to use for Apex testing? I know that publishing an article requires the KbManagement.PublishingService class, however I don't see anything that can add fake data to the ViewStat part of a Knowledge Base Article.

```
Process__ViewStat p = new Process__ViewStat();
p.ViewCount = 1000;
insert p;
```

Returns a compile error of:

```
Field is not writeable: Process__ViewStat.ViewCount
```